# Firestore Cloud Function timestamp conversion

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the timestamp of an event (onCreate, onDelete etc) from its

```
timestamp: '2017-11-10T20:24:55.803055Z'
```

format into seconds since 1970. I'm wonder if I need to figure out how to parse the timestamp or if there is function I can call in my cloud functions to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions doesn't have anything special to help you with date conversions.  It's just running node.js in a managed environment.

I'd recommend looking into the [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) module, which has all kinds of date and time utilities, especially [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know the firebase command for pushing new modules?  I'm looking at the documentation now I can't quite find it.

Comment: appears to just be a normal  "firebase deploy"  testing now

Answer (score 1):

the timestamp from firebase/firestore comes in this format

```
date: Timestamp {
seconds: 1582250739,
nanoseconds: 934000000}
```

to convert this values i use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) like @Doug said.

```
moment.unix(item.date.seconds).fromNow()
```